# How to use a source file in a create-react-app in a separate nodejs script?

Tags: node.js, webpack, create-react-app

I have a `create-react-app` project using Typescript. I am writing a standalone nodejs script to do some data processing.

When I run `react-scripts build`, it compiles everything into chunks in a build folder. How do I import one of the project's `.ts` files in my script to run separately?

I found a solution (below) but please comment or answer if you have a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Place your script in a subdirectory and extend your project's `tsconfig`. Override `noEmit`, `outDir`, and `module` compiler options if necessary.

**myscript/tsconfig.json**:

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "index.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmit": false,
    "outDir": "build"
  }
}
```

**myscript/index.ts**:

```
import { foo } from '../src/foo'
console.log(foo)
```

Then you can compile and run your script directly:

```sh
# compile
cd myscript
tsc

# run script
node build/myscript/index.js
```